# update nested model via knockout mapping plugin

Tags: knockout.js

I have custom knockout mapping for model wich contains other models.

```
var InnerModel = function(data) {
    var self = this;
    ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, self);   

    var customVar = true;
};

var Model = function() {
    var self = this;
    var customMapping = {
            'InnerModel': {
                update: function (options) {
                    return ko.observable(new InnerModel(options.data));
                }
            }
    };    
    ko.mapping.fromJS(forecastData, customMapping, self);   

}
```

This works fine when model is created first time. However, this doesn't work properly when model is updated (when data are loaded one more time via ajax).

The reason is that I do not need to create `new InnerModel` on `update`. During `new InnerModel` I am loosing some values of custom properties I have created within `InnerModel`. For example, I have `InnerModel.customVar` that is set to `true` by default, however, later during some manipulations it has value `false`. But if I do mapping it is always set back to `true`.

How to write update mapping properly?

Answer (score 0):

`customVar` is being reset to `true` because in your `Model` mapping options, you are calling `new InnerModel(options.data)` and you have `customVar` set to `true` in your `InnerModel` function. Likewise, if you had `var customVar = false;` in that function, then everytime you updated your model `customVar` would always be reset to false.

A simple solution would be to tell the Knockout mapping plugin to ignore that property. So your function could be changed to this:

```
var InnerModel = function(data) {
    var self = this,
        mappingOpt = {
           'ignore': ['customVar']
        };
    ko.mapping.fromJS(data, mappingOpt, self);   

    var customVar = true;
};
```

That way, each time you instantiated a new `InnerModel` `customVar` would be set to true; and any subsequent updates to the model (via AJAX or otherwise) would ignore that property's value and leave it intact.

#### EDIT

Looking at it the problem again, I realized that my above answer wouldn't solve your problem if `customVar` was a purely client side property(not one that is included in your AJAX updates). In that case, the problem **isn't with the mapping plugin** - it is due to the fact that when you update your model you are instantantiating a new `InnerModel` that has `customVar` set to `true`.

So you'd have to implement some custom logic yourself to preserve your existing values of `customVar`.

Comment: I do understand everything you wrote, I know it. However, I still not able to find answer to my question. Is not there some way no to create "new Model" during update, but create it on 'init', but update on 'update'. I am not able to update it.